# How do I get unique running apps in bottom panel for each KDE/Kubuntu workspace?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, workspaces

I am using KDE 4.13.3 (I believe it is the kubuntu-desktop download) on Ubuntu 14.04. I changed Systems Settings->Workspace Appearance and Behavior->Workspace Behavior->Virtual Desktops to have 4.

However, if I have Firefox running in Workspace 1, it shows up, not just in the bottom panel of Workspace 1, but also Workspace 2, Workspace 3, and Workspace 4, partially defeating the purpose of having Workspaces in the first place, and not what I would expect as the default behavior.

Is there a way I can get applications started in one Workspace to only display in the bottom panel of the Workspace they were started in - or is that bottom panel for "all workspaces"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the task manager located on the bottom panel -> access Settings -> select "Only show tasks from the current desktop".

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, I don't see a Task Manager icon on my bottom panel even though Add Widgets shows it checked. But when I right clicked on the bottom panel one of two choices was "Task Manager Settings" which allowed me to check "Only show tasks from the current desktop" and uncheck "Only show tasks from the current activity".

Comment: There is no task manager icon, of course. The task manager (which is just one of the many plasmoids available) just shows your open windows: if you click over one of those, or over the empty space which is reserved to the task manager as you did, you can access it's settings. It makes no sense to have an icon for every single component present in the bottom panel, it would be a nightmare if you add many. Another possibility is to unlock widgets (plasmoids), click the cashew icon on the end of the panel and access the task manager's settings by hovering over it and clicking the wrench icon.